MakeSpriteFont.exe downloaded off github says "can't find font" no matter what
MakeSpriteFont.exe downloaded off github says "can't find font" no matter what. I tried copying fonts to its local dir, I tried specific path for the font, in root, windows font folder, local, nothing works. I tried all lower case name, with extension and without, in "". nothing
Are there previous .exe versions I could try.
System is windows 10

Dan: Since you solved it (on Staging Ground), please post the solution as an answer.

What did you try exactly? Docs are here. For example, MakeSpriteFont "Comic Sans MS" myfile.spritefont /FontSize:16.
